# Open MessageBird widget chat from JS code

Tags: javascript, messagebird

I'm using messagebird omnichannel widget for my website.
And put the snippet code already. The widget runs great BTW.

I did saw toggleChat function, but it can only hide the chat window.

How can I force-open the chat widget from javascript code ?

Comment: Please share what you have tried yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MessageBird developer is here :)

Good catch! There was a small issue with `toggleChat` method.

We just fixed it and deployed the fix, you can use `toggleChat()` now.

As you mentioned, `toggleChat` should do it - to open/hide the widget, but it didn't work. The issue that we had was the following:
you had to pass `true` to open the chat and pass `false` to close it. It is not obvious when we have the name of the method like `toggleChat`, I agree! :)

Anyway, it's fixed but feel free to reach me if you have any other questions about the widget or our other products.